# Как в termux авто стартовать node+express при загрузке телефона

Tags: node.js, express, boot

На "телефоне" `Quectel SC20 c Android 7.1.2` установлены:

- `termux(0.72)+termux:boot(0.5)+termux:api(0.33)`
- `node+express+forever`

Настроен `sshd`, успешно запускаемый плагином `termux:boot` при включении телефона.

Странички для `node+express` закинут в папку `~/web`.

С телефоном работаю из PuTTY через USB.

Из терминала сервер нормально стартует и работает, командная строка для запуска из папки `HOME` такая:

```
forever start -a -o out.log -e err.log web/app.js
```

Но если я добавляю эту строку в файл для авто-запуска, сервер не запускается, содержимое файла `~/.termux/boot/start_sshd` такое:

```
sshd
forever start -a -o ~/out.log -e ~/err.log web/app.js
date > date.log
```

После срабатывания скрипта в папке `HOME` создан файл `date.log`, а сервер не стартовал.

1. В чём проблема, как её решить?
2. Может есть другой способ авто запуска сервера `node+express`?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл подсказку [тут](https://github.com/termux/termux-app/issues/621#issuecomment-450969289).

Вот как выглядит рабочий скрипт авто-запуска сервера `node+expres` и `sshd`. 
(На всякий случай добавил в скрипт защиту от повторного запуска, *есть у меня подозрение что* скрипт авто-запуска время от времени запускается повторно.)

```
ps -o comm | grep sshd | grep -v grep
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 sshd
else
 echo 'running sshd'
fi

ps -o args | grep app.js | grep -v grep
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 node /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/forever start -a -o out.log -e err.log web/app.js
else
 echo 'running app.js'
fi
```

P.S. Похоже что для авто-запуска обязательно требуется вызвать реальный бинарный файл, не через символьную ссылку, но это не точно...